# Structuring JSF file in web application

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am making a web application (JSF) and I wonder how to structure the files. I have different resources a user can interact with such as "Questions".

Would I make a folder named "questions" and do the following:

- index.xhtml --> Lists the questions
- add.xhtml --> add new question
- edit.xhtml --> edit question
- show.xhtml --> show question

Or would you call the files questions.xhtml, question-add.xhtml etc?

**Or** are both alternatives wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding meaningful prefix or suffix is the better way in my opinion , or at least placing in meaningful folder is fine as well

adding prefix/suffix will speed up your coding (by making it easier to find/modify files in project) and will make you partners life easier...(while trying to understand an already made code)

Comment: So you wouldn't make a folder for each "resource" like this in the project?

Comment: define resource...? Anyway, I would create folders with logical meaning , for example "Questions" folder to hold all question related files, or Entity Folder (to hold Question/Answer/etc ....) and Actions Folder (to hold add/edit/remove/etc ....)

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, for small projects you might want to keep it in a single folder. For larger projects subfolders will help you keep a better overview.